# How to check multiple values with same field name inside the array

Tags: php, mysql

```
foreach(
  $db->getRecordSet(
    $sqlinfo,
    array(
      ':job_user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id'],                                           
      ':job_root'=>0,
      ":job_status"=>2
    )
  ) as $rows
)
```

The given foreach loop works fine, I want to add `":job_status"=>0`,

with the `":job_status"=>2,` is there a way to do it within the foreach loop.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Just get a boolean back if there are duplicates, filter duplicates out, or something else?

Comment: filter duplicates out, like  when i echo $rows['job_status];  i only want job_stauts that are equal to 2 and 0,

Comment: how can be `job_status` at the same time  `2 and 0`?. I think you need  `2 OR 0`

Comment: array(
      ':job_user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id'],                                           
      ':job_root'=>0,
      ":job_status"=>2
     ":job_status"=>0)

Comment: but it is not working it will 0nly filter out the job_status that is 2 , not the zero

Comment: Which ORM/DB access library is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, i added filter on my query which is $sqlinfo, job_status = 2 AND job_status = 0.